# How to get list of all objects? - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

**I need a list of the objects included in the db: tables, sequences, etc...**

---

Getting the list of tables was the only thing I was able to find out.

---

**Any ideas for what I could use in order to obtain everything?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, as well as the system catalog.

http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html

E.g.,

**List Sequences**

```
SELECT relname
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'S'
AND relnamespace IN (
    SELECT oid
    FROM pg_namespace
    WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
    AND nspname != 'information_schema'
);
```

**List Triggers**

```
SELECT trg.tgname AS trigger_name
  FROM pg_trigger trg, pg_class tbl
 WHERE trg.tgrelid = tbl.oid
   AND tbl.relname !~ '^pg_';
-- or
SELECT tgname AS trigger_name
  FROM pg_trigger
 WHERE tgname !~ '^pg_';

-- with INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

SELECT DISTINCT trigger_name
  FROM information_schema.triggers
 WHERE trigger_schema NOT IN
       ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

Answer (score 0):

All objects across cluster can be listed thru
The utility `pg_objectlist`.

`github` link in below.

https://github.com/dataxorg/pg_objectlist

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use pg_dump with the "schema only" option

```
pg_dump --schema-only databasename > fname.sql
```

That will give you definitions in SQL, how the objects might have been created.